# Font family and font style is not working in m pdf

Tags: php, html, fonts

i try to convert html to m pdf it work fine. But font family and bold tag not apply in pdf 
my config_font.php code is...
`enter code here`
`<?php 
    $this->fontdata = array(
        "HelveticaNeue" => array(
        'R' => "HelveticaNeue.ttf",
        'B' => "HelveticaNeueBold.ttf",
        'I' => "HelveticaNeueItalic.ttf",
        'BI' => "HelveticaNeueBoldItalic.ttf",
         ),
     );
     ?>
<h6 style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom:8px;">
    <small>Device Location :<b><?php echo $device_location; ?> </b></small>
</h6>`

Here bold tag and font family  is not working in mpdf and its work fine in html page
plz help me

Comment: Pradeep, did you try giving in styling of h6 just to check whether issue is with the pdf

Comment: html and php can't be fixed. <small>Device Location : $device_location;</small> must be <small>Device Location : <?php echo $device_location; ?></small>